# Removing many types of chars from a Python string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some string X and I wish to remove semicolons, periods, commas, colons, etc, all in one go. Is there a way to do this that doesn't require a big chain of .replace(somechar,"") calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method with a first argument of `None`:

```
string2 = string1.translate(None, ";.,:")
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`filter` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
string2 = filter(lambda x: x not in ";,.:", string1)
```

Note that both of these options only work for non-Unicode strings and only in Python 2.

Comment: Is this better/worse than using re?

Comment: @JohnSmith: I would suspect that this way is more efficient than getting regular expressions involved, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: @John Smith: better/worse with respect to what? perhaps you should edit your question stating your full requirements.

Comment: @carlosdc I suppose with respect to runtime/overhead

Comment: @jwodder: `.translate()` is about six times faster than a compiled regex and eight times faster than a `re.sub()` call. `filter()` is slower than everything and doesn't actually return a string.

Comment: @Blender: `filter` does return a string in Python 2 when the iterable is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub` to pattern match and replace.  The following replaces `h` and `i` only with empty strings:

```
In [1]: s = 'byehibyehbyei'

In [1]: re.sub('[hi]', '', s)
Out[1]: 'byebyebye'
```

Don't forget to `import re`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> foo = "asdf;:,*_-"
>>> re.sub('[;:,*_-]', '', foo)
'asdf'
```

- `[;:,*_-]` - List of characters to be matched
- `''` - Replace match with nothing
- Using the string `foo`.

For more information take a look at the [`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the speed, but here's another example without using `re`.

```
commas_and_stuff = ",+;:"
words = "words; and stuff!!!!"
cleaned_words = "".join(c for c in words if c not in commas_and_stuff)
```

Gives you:

> 'words and stuff!!!!'